# Get android app sandbox path

Tags: android, file

My app downloads image files for offline use. Using the DownloadManager, the files are saved to the app's /data/ folder (retrieved with `Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath()`). When displaying the images, the function `File.exists` for the path `/data/filename` returns false. When I provide the full path (kinda harcoded with the following function) everything works.

```
private static String getImageUri(Context c, String name) {
    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + File.separator +
            "Android" + File.separator + "data" + File.separator +
            c.getPackageName() +  File.separator +
            "files" + File.separator + name;
}
```

It seems the File api requires the full path but I couldn't find a more elegant way of getting the full path.

Is there a better way of doing this? Another api that allows r/w and treats paths the same way the DownloadManager does? Or a better way of retrieving the full path?

Comment: "Using the DownloadManager, the files are saved to the app's /data/ folder" -- `DownloadManager` has no rights to work with that directory.

Comment: @CommonsWare I beg the differ. The line `request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context, Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), name);` works.

Comment: By your own admission, `DownloadManager` is storing the data in `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare The code returns the path `storage/emulated/0/android/data/com.package.app/files/data`. This is where the files are stored. `DownloadManager` stores there using the short command above but I managed to access them using the File api only with the method above. My goal is accessing them in a more elegant manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The code returns the path `storage/emulated/0/android/data/com.package.app/files/data`.

I assume that your lowercase `android` is a typo, as that location should be `Android`.

You can obtain that location more simply via `getExternalFilesDir()` (method on `Context`), though you will need to append the trailing `data` segment yourself.

> The line request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context, Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), name); works

It would be simpler — and far more compliant with [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request.html#setDestinationInExternalFilesDir%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) — to just use `request.setDestnationInExternalFilesDir(context, null, name)`. Then, your downloaded file would be in the location `new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), name)`.